# How do I make an item list with headings?

Tags: google-sheets

I have columns like the left two below, but want columns like the right two. I'm not sure if there is even a name for this transformation, or what it is. Query with Group By seems the closest I could find, but wants to aggregate the data items rather than listing them in each group. The left columns would be created by merging various data entry sheets, reordering columns, and sorting by column A. I've got that figured out. But converting to the format in columns C & D baffles me. I guess it is more of a report-writer function: do I need to write a script function with a loop to achieve this result, or is there something I am overlooking?

```
        A                 B                C      D
A group - subgroup1     data 1          A group - subgroup1     
A group - subgroup1     data 2                  data 1
A group - subgroup1     data 3                  data 2
A group - subgroup2     data 4                  data 3
A group - subgroup2     data 5          A group - subgroup2     
A group - subgroup2     data 6                  data 4
A group - subgroup2     data 7                  data 5
B group - subgroup1     data 8                  data 6
B group - subgroup1     data 9                  data 7
C group - subgroup1     data 10         B group - subgroup1     
C group - subgroup1     data 11                 data 8
C group - subgroup3     data 12                 data 9
C group - subgroup3     data 13         C group - subgroup1     
C group - subgroup3     data 14                 data 10
                                                data 11
                                        C group - subgroup3     
                                                data 12
                                                data 13
                                                data 14
```

Answer (score 2):

As @ttarchala suggested, Pivot tables is a useful functionality. I did try to make a `query` solution though. It's NOT exactly what you wanted. But, it's close, IMO:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(A2:B15,"select max(B) group by B pivot A")&"",, 999999999999))&" ", " ", 0))
```

The idea here is to fake a aggregation function like `MAX`, So that we can pivot inside `query`. The rest of the formula is simply to remove blanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a pivot table. Define columns A and B as dimensions of the pivot table, then put both of them on the left (vertical) axis.

This will not achieve exactly what you want - headings will not be on a separate line - but will enable useful things like automatic recalculation and subtotals.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to proposed answers by https://stackoverflow.com/users/34704/ttarchala and https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i I was able to come up with the exact formulas needed, although it took two steps.

The data was in Column A & B, I wanted the results in C & D, so I put the temporary results in E & F. So the first formula goes in E1, and the second in C1.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(split(Transpose(split(Textjoin("█",TRUE,Transpose(QUERY({A1:A14&"¤␣","␣¤"&B1:B14},"select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"))),"█")),"¤"))

=Arrayformula(if(E:F="␣","",E:F))
```

The pivot table was helpful. I preprocessed my two columns of data so that header column had a trailing ¤␣ and the data a leading ␣¤. Then after the Transpose(split(Textjoin(Transpose))) stuff, I wound up with a single column that I could split on ¤ and get two columns, with the desired-to-be-blank cells containing ␣. The second pass (because I couldn't figure out how to join the formulas) was to replace the ␣ with nothingness into the result columns.